# How to write a graph with d3.js graph

Tags: d3.js

I want to pick up some data from a DB mysql from a form in a website by a button and make the graph in a canvas using `d3.js` any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Joseph! Please edit your question and include the code you have written so far. That will help folks to understand your problem better.

Comment: Can you post your data sample and a sketch of the graph you want to achieve?

Comment: use the `fetch` API, use one of the format parsers of D3, create the graph you want, add as much interaction (brush, drag, tooltip) as you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load data from JSON, CSV, and text file.

For example, to load a JSON file you can use `d3.json()` as shown below.

```js
d3.json('data.json', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Same you can parse data from a CSV file. The D3 function `d3.csv()` takes a file name as an input, processes the file and loads the data into an array of objects. Note that the first row of the csv file does not get printed. This is because the first row is treated as the column name and rest of the rows are considered as the data. The data object loaded by d3 uses these column names as the object's properties and hence are converted to object keys.

```js
d3.csv('data.csv', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

While loading data from an external source, D3 returns an argument called `error`. You can use this argument to check whether your data got loaded successfully.

```js
d3.json('data.json', function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
        return console.warn(error);
    }

 // Manage the data

});
```

If there is some error while loading your data, say your data is malformed; D3 will return an `error` object. You can check for errors and take a decision based on this.

Here you have an example using the function `d3.csv()`:

```js
let svg = d3.select('svg');
let margin = 200,
  width = svg.attr('width') - margin,
  height = svg.attr('height') - margin;

svg.append('text')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(100,0)')
  .attr('x', 50).attr('y', 50)
  .attr('font-size', '20px')
  .attr('class', 'title')
  .text('Population bar chart');

let x = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width]).padding(0.4);
let y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

let g = svg.append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + 100 + ',' + 100 + ')');

 d3.csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/teocci/c0effdc5851bc7a07375106f1d9f4772/raw/1a22006fd5c8747dedee88e9f4980ea4155f9ba3/data.csv', function(error, data) {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.year;
  }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.population;
  })]);

  g.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
    .append('text')
    .attr('y', height - 250)
    .attr('x', width - 125)
    .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
    .attr('font-size', '18px')
    .attr('stroke', 'blue')
    .style('fill', 'blue')
    .text('year');

  g.append('g')
    .append('text')
    .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
    .attr('y', 6)
    .attr('dy', '-50px')
    .attr('dx', '-100px')
    .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
    .attr('font-size', '18px')
    .attr('stroke', 'blue')
    .style('fill', 'blue')
    .text('population');

  g.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 0)')
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))

  g.selectAll('.bar')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'bar')
    .on('mouseover', onMouseOver)
    .on('mouseout', onMouseOut)
    .attr('x', function(d) {
      return x(d.year);
    })
    .attr('y', function(d) {
      return y(d.population);
    })
    .attr('width', x.bandwidth()).transition()
    .ease(d3.easeLinear).duration(200)
    .delay(function(d, i) {
      return i * 25;
    })

    .attr('height', function(d) {
      return height - y(d.population);
    });
});


function onMouseOver(d, i) {
  d3.select(this)
    .attr('class', 'highlight');

  d3.select(this)
    .transition()
    .duration(200)
    .attr('width', x.bandwidth() + 5)
    .attr('y', function(d) {
      return y(d.population) - 10;
    })
    .attr('height', function(d) {
      return height - y(d.population) + 10;
    });

  g.append('text')
    .attr('class', 'val')
    .attr('x', function() {
      return x(d.year);
    })

    .attr('y', function() {
      return y(d.value) - 10;
    })
}

function onMouseOut(d, i) {
  d3.select(this)
    .attr('class', 'bar');

  d3.select(this)
    .transition()
    .duration(200)
    .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
    .attr('y', function(d) {
      return y(d.population);
    })
    .attr('height', function(d) {
      return height - y(d.population);
    });

  d3.selectAll('.val')
    .remove()
}
```

```css
.bar {
  fill: green;
}

.highlight {
  fill: red;
}

.title {
  fill: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500"></svg>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```